# Possible to whiten teeth beyond natural color without veneers?

Tags: dentistry, brushing-teeth, bleach-teeth-whitening

My teeth, in some parts, are impossibly yellow and do not whiten no matter what procedures have been done. I am seeking out a method to artificially whiten the yellow parts without veneers or resin put on them. In other words, if they can't be naturally whitened, I want them artificially whitened.

I, however, refuse veneers because it doesn't make my teeth whiter -- it just covers the teeth and it's purely fake. I want some sort of epoxy or enamel-mimicking agent that can bind to my teeth and change the real color of the dentin to be yellow and keep it that way. Or some other scientific way of doing this without veneers, resin or implants. I refuse to believe that it's impossible to force dentin to look white. I want my teeth to be Hollywood white without veneers/dentures/etc.

I would like the natural yellow color to be artificially cleaned and painted/bonded to force the color of the yellow to turn white -- not have something fake cover the natural color. As stated, I've tried every professional whitening possible from dentists, etc. and it will not make my teeth super white.

Comment: For this topic, I'm not sure you're going to find anything here beyond what a dentist could have told you.

Answer (score 2):

There is no healthy way. Whitening/bleaching do not change the shape of your teeth but alas, dentine doe not bleach well, if at all (it just gets more sensitive to temperature change). Veneers done well will have a 'good' shape to ensure gum health. As for trying to find something to paint on, let's explore that if you place a opaque white dental liquid filling but it being so thin, will eventually wear off real fast with everyday brushing. Sorry, no miracle solution.

Comment: I don't understand how the link supports your answer.

Comment: The link shows a product that dentists use to add tint and color to dentures and crowns. It is to show you that adding that tint to a person's natural teeth (and hardening/curing it with a blue light) is not a long-lasting solution at all